# How to select certain number of rows from large query result set in Teradata sql

Tags: sql, select, teradata, sql-limit

I am new to Teradata sql and I have a query that selects over one million rows.  I want to write teradata sql to select the first 500,000 rows, then the next 500,000 rows and then the last 100,000 + rows in my data set.  For the first set I know I can use SELECT * FROM QRY1 ORDER BY 1 SAMPLE 500000, but to select 5000001 to 1000000, how can I do that?
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: You need an `order by` for your question to make any sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Teradata, you can use `rank()` and `qualify`:

```
select *
from qry1
qualify on rank() over(order by id) between 5000001 and 1000000
order by id
```

This assumes that column `id` can be use to sort the records.